# Unknown Item type error in socialengine even registered in manifest.php file of module

Tags: zend-framework, exception, socialengine

I am getting strange error. please help

I am creating custom module named "Advinvite"

I have created table : "engine4_advinvite_matchinvites"

I have created DbTable : "Advinvite_Model_DbTable_Matchinvites"

I have created DbTable's Row class model : "Advinvite_Model_Matchinvite" And Primary key in the table is "matchinvite_id"

I have also created Api: "Advinvite_Api_Core"

The main part I have also registered the item in manifest.php file of settings folder of module like :

```
// Items ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  'items' => array(
    'advinvite_matchinvite',
  )
```

Now regarding Error :

I am getting error "Unknown Item Type : advinvite_matchinvite" when i want to use

`Engine:Api:_()->getItem('advinvite_matchinvite',its_Identity)`

I am sending the manifest file code too below. please can you check it for me and help me. It has been come in my life first time (weird error) and i am trying to solve this for last three/four days. Even Everything i did correctly why it is happening Not understanding. Please help me mate. It will be very appreciated.

And also if you can help me with this too means Routes are also not working....Don't know why these both errors are coming

Help Me Please.

Manifest.php Code:

```
<?php return array (
  'package' => 
  array (
    'type' => 'module',
    'name' => 'advinvite',
    'version' => '4.0.0',
    'path' => 'application/modules/Advinvite',
    'title' => 'Advanced Invites',
    'description' => 'This will invite the users for matches and nets',
    'author' => 'Gitesh Dang',
    'callback' => 
    array (
      'class' => 'Engine_Package_Installer_Module',
    ),
    'actions' => 
    array (
      0 => 'install',
      1 => 'upgrade',
      2 => 'refresh',
      3 => 'enable',
      4 => 'disable',
    ),
    'directories' => 
    array (
      0 => 'application/modules/Advinvite',
    ),
    'files' => 
    array (
      0 => 'application/languages/en/advinvite.csv',
    ),
    // Items ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  'items' => array(
    'advinvite_matchinvite',
  ),
  // Routes --------------------------------------------------------------------
  'routes' => array(
    'advinvite_general' => array(
      'route' => 'invites/:action/*',
      'defaults' => array(
        'module' => 'advinvite',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => '(match|matchview)',
      ),
      'reqs' => array(
        'action' => '\D+',
      )
    ),
  )
  ),
); ?>
```

Waiting for postive response.
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Mates,
It has been fixed.
The issue was minor :)

Items was registered in package array and it should be registered outside of package array. Package array should be closed to files array only.

Corrected Manifest File :

```
    <?php return array (
      'package' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'module',
        'name' => 'advinvite',
        'version' => '4.0.0',
        'path' => 'application/modules/Advinvite',
        'title' => 'Advanced Invites',
        'description' => 'This will invite the users for matches and nets',
        'author' => 'Gitesh Dang',
        'callback' => 
        array (
          'class' => 'Engine_Package_Installer_Module',
        ),
        'actions' => 
        array (
          0 => 'install',
          1 => 'upgrade',
          2 => 'refresh',
          3 => 'enable',
          4 => 'disable',
        ),
        'directories' => 
        array (
          0 => 'application/modules/Advinvite',
        ),
        'files' => 
        array (
          0 => 'application/languages/en/advinvite.csv',
        ),
      ),
 // Items ---------------------------------------------------------------------
      'items' => array(
        'advinvite_matchinvite',
      ),
      // Routes --------------------------------------------------------------------
      'routes' => array(
        'advinvite_general' => array(
          'route' => 'invites/:action/*',
          'defaults' => array(
            'module' => 'advinvite',
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => '(match|matchview)',
          ),
          'reqs' => array(
            'action' => '\D+',
          )
        ),
      )
    ); ?>
```

Cheers !! :)